# Передача данных между контроллерами angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть несколько контроллеров в ангуляре.
Как мне из rootScop-а или из одного контроллера обратиться к значению/функции другого?

```
<div id="AdminDiv"  ng-controller="AdminController" >

<div>
<div id="SettingsDiv" ng-controller="SettingsController" >

<div>
---- 
myApp.controller('AdminController', function($scope,$http,$rootScope) {
      $scope.get_data= function () {
              alert("я из AdminController");
      }
      $scope.get_data_in_SettingsController= function () {
              //как мне здесь сослаться на SettingsController?
      }
}
myApp.controller('SettingsController', function($scope,$http,$rootScope) {
      $scope.get_data= function () {
              alert("я из SettingsController");
      }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен broadcast или внешний storage-модуль, в котором данные должны сохраняться между вызовами. Последнее - очень плохое решение.

Answer (score 1):

В голову с ходу приходит пару решений:

1) Создать сервис, который будет содержать необходимые данные и методы для работы с ними, чтобы иметь возможность изменять и считывать эти данные в разных контроллерах (не забудьте про **$watch**'ы для данных, если это не объекты, чтобы данные обновлялись во всех контроллерах, в которых данны нужны).

2) Если Вам нужно, чтобы один контроллер вызвал какой-нибудь метод из другого, то можно использовать `$rootScope.$broadcast('eventName')` в вызывающем контроллере и `$rootScope.$on('eventName', eventFunc)` в контроллере, который будет выполнять вызывающуюся функцию `eventFunc`. (Лучше почитать [здесь](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). Обратите внимание на $emit).

3) Пытаться найти значение через **$rootScope**, используя **$parent**, **$$childHead**, **$$childTail**... Но это совершенно неправильный подход и считается костылем.

Answer (score 0):

Доступ к `$scope` другого контроллера производится посредством следующей конструкции

```
angular.element($("#outer")).scope();
```

Пример - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXkjc/1008/)